# same Unique ID for upload data from csv to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import data from csv file to mysql table.from below code i am able to import my csv data to mysql table. In that mysql table there is a column called **"ord"** which should have same unique ID (need to increment by one) for each time during data upload from csv to mysql table. i tried by update query but after increment once it is giving the same unique number to other next uploading . Not sure where i made wrong and need your advice to correct my code.

```html
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('upload',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','D:/');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "Book1.csv"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

 $col1 = $col[0];
 $col2 = $col[1];
 $col3 = $col[2];
 $col4 = $col[3];
  $col5 = $col[4];
  
  // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

$query = "INSERT INTO unique_entry(ord,size,colour,qty,Creation_Date) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."',now())";
$s     = mysql_query($query, $connect );
 }
 mysql_query("
    UPDATE unique_entry 
    SET ord= ' ".$col1." ' + 1 
    WHERE Creation_Date = now()
");
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: My Table Stricture id - int,Auto Increment-Primary, ord-int, size,colour,qty is varchar and creation_date is date & time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the update query outside of while loop. So the query will not execute all the times. Only for the last entry it will update. So we can do two things.
1) Include that update query inside the while loop.
2) increment the $col1 value before insert query and execute query. Then it will work for all entries.

Comment: Hi Pujitha Vamsi, I have tried with your option 1 but field is not in cementing. for your option 2, can you please let me know what would be the query stracture for increment the $col1 value before insert query...

Comment: Hi, Can u share me your sample book1.csv file. so that i will give u the exact code of it.

Comment: Hi, Below is my Book1.csv structure for importing data...

ord size colour qty Creation_Date
1 S White 120 
1 M Black 500

Comment: You are retriving the $col1 value from csv file only. So before insert query add as $col1=$col1+1; So it will increment it to 1 before insert query. So once the above specified line is executed the value will be updated and the no need of update query.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your advice and it works! another point is if i want to remove col1(ord) field from book1.csv then shall i need to increment the col1 field first then trigger the insert statement

Comment: If you are removing the ord from csv file and if that incrementing line is there it will give u the errors. So before the while loop initialize the $col1 with zero. then automatically the incremented values will be saved into the database.

Comment: Thanks for your Helpful advice! I will do it accordingly.